# Rails: get all boolean columns from model and map their name and value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way I can get all the boolean columns from a model and map their values?

Something like (very pseudocode):

```
Template.columns_hash.where(type: :boolean).map(&:value)
```

Any thoughts? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will get all the column names filtered by the desired type,

```
Template.columns.select{ |c| c.type == :boolean }.map(&:name)
```

Comment: Gonna go with this one since it's simplest, although I used this in a `columns.each { |column| active << column.gsub('_', ' ') if send(column) } ` line to get it only if it's true. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could work:

```
columns = Model.columns.select { |column| column.type == :boolean }.map(&:name).join ','
Model.pluck columns
```

For mapping the values you can use `pluck`.

It'd produce a query like:

```
SELECT column1, column1, column1, ... FROM "model"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct. Ruby lambdas should be with curly braces. This is for `ActiveRecord` by the way.

```
Template.columns.select{ |column| column.sql_type == "boolean" }.map(&:name)
```